# Genymotion android emulator adb shell can't write /etc/hosts

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have some virtual hosts under my localhost and I need to add it to /etc/hosts in Genmotion android emulator.

for that I used in windows cmd:

```
adb shell
mount -o remount,rw /system
echo "192.168.xxx.xxx   my_virtualhost" > /etc/hosts
```

I have tried that to this virtual device:
**Google Galaxy Nexus - 4.2.2 - API 17 - 720x1280**
and all ok. I got root shell and my_virtualhost is added to /etc/hosts

But when I tried to do same on other virtual device:  **Google Nexus 9 - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 1536x2048** Don't work and I got this:

```
adb shell
mount -o remount,rw /system
echo "192.168.xxx.xxx   my_virtualhost" > /etc/hosts > /etc/hostsvbox86p:/ # mount -o remount,rw /system
mount: '/dev/block/sda6'->'/system': Device or resource busy
1|vbox86p:/ # echo "192.168.xxx.xxx   my_virtualhost" > /etc/hosts
```

Any idea how to solve this  or another way to edit /etc/host ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my OnePlus 5.

Had to upload modified `hosts` file to `/sdcard` and then copy it to `/etc/hosts` via [Root Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.rootexplorer) app which handled rw remount properly on the fly.